# Copy Cell value and Change cell Value

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet of my Jobs. In Column F is status of Job e.g. OrderGot, Processing, Cleared..and H is Bill Amount.... at last there is total colomn which calculate the Total of Bill Amount. I always add rows to add the Jobs.

I want to  a formula which may check If F1="Cleared" then it deduct that amount from the Total Sum.

[image]

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` to calculate the Grand Total, excluding (`<>`) "Cleared".

Answer (score -1):

Use the Subtotal - SUMIFS  as follows

=SUBTOTAL(9,H2:H6)-SUMIFS(H2:H6,F2:F6,"Cleared")